# Why do I get this error in JavaScript React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**ERROR** - `Parse error. '}' expected`

I have problems with this code, in this I send to call some data to place them in a graph, I occupy reject and work with react but I can not find how to solve it.

```
vehiculoPorColores = () => {
const _this = this
fetch("/live/graph/color")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(datos => {
    const vehicleKey = Object.keys(datos);
    console.log(datos)
    _this.setState(
      {
        vehiculosC: vehicleKey.map((e, i) => (
          { 
            name: vehicleKey[i], datos ,[e]
           }
        )
      },() => {setTimeout(this.vehiculoPorColores, 1000)}
  )
})
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z24bG.png)

Comment: You should use an IDE or editor that shows compilation errors. For example, using jsfiddle, you can easily see what's wrong with your parentheses:
https://jsfiddle.net/5mvxpyfr/

Comment: Just a tip; the entire point of lambda functions is to avoid doing stuff like `_this = this`. You don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing `}`, error message is saying it expects a closing brace. Code formatting will help spot these things, when defining multiple object values is common practice to put these values on separate lines.

This `{ name: vehicleKey[i], datos, [e] }` becomes:

```
{ 
  name: vehicleKey[i], 
  datos,
  [e]
}
```

Helps to spot bugs like the syntax error `[e]` in the object key assignment.

This is what produces the syntax error:

```
const baz = 'baz'
const syntaxErrorExample = { 
  foo: 'tar', 
  [baz] // <-- Syntax error
}
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Can be changed to:

```
const baz = 'baz'
const example = { 
  foo: 'tar', 
  [baz]: undefined // <-- Works
}
```

```js
class Foo {
  vehiculoPorColores = () => {
    fetch("/live/graph/color")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(datos => {
      const vehicleKey = Object.keys(datos);

      const newState = {
        vehiculosC: vehicleKey.map((e, i) => { 
          return {
            name: vehicleKey[i], 
            datos, 
            [e]: undefined
          }
        })
      }

      this.setState(newState, () => {
        setTimeout(this.vehiculoPorColores, 1000)
      })
    })
  }
}

console.log(true) // Made it to this line, so no syntax error
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```